# MongoDb query on byte[] with the C# driver throwing ExpressionNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to MongoDB and I have the following query

```
var personList = collection.Find
  (p => p.EmailAddressSha512 == PiSha512.CreateSha512(emailAddress.ToLower())).ToList();
```

Executing the query throws the exception

```
MongoDB.Driver.Linq.ExpressionNotSupportedException:
'Expression not supported: (p.EmailAddressSha512 == value(System.Byte[])).
```

`EmailAddressSha512` is a `byte[]` and `PiSha512.CreateSha512(emailAddress.ToLower())` returns a `byte[]`.

While the exception is thrown by the driver (latest version, 2.21.0) and displayed in debug mode, it appears to be handled and the query executes correctly and returns the expected person list. I'm wondering a few things.

1. Why is the exception exception being thrown?
2. Why is this working correctly in spite of the exception being thrown?
3. What can I do to stop the exception being thrown?

If I convert EmailAddressSha512 to a string and convert it to Base64 it works fine, so it has something to do with the comparison of byte[] types. My main confusion is why it throws the exception but works fine. All my tests pass correctly and there's an index on EmailAddressSha512 that's being used.

**Workaround**

A suggestion by @Nikolay works around the issue. If the query uses Filter.Eq instead then no exception is thrown.

```
        var personList =
            collection.Find(Builders<PersonDb>.
                Filter.Eq(p => p.EmailAddressSha512,
                    PiSha512.CreateSha512(emailAddress.ToLower()))).ToList();
```

Comment: see "Unsupported LINQ or Builder expressions" here https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/frequently_encountered_issues/

Answer (score 1):

The `Find` method you are calling takes an expression, not a delegate. Expressions passed as arguments are often used for interpretation rather than execution.

1. In your case, while interpreting the expression, the mongodb driver detected unsupported constructs - `PiSha512.CreateSha512(emailAddress.ToLower())` and it informed you about it in an exception
2. it can't work correctly because the driver didn't build a query to mongodb using your expression.
3. To avoid this error, execute your code `PiSha512.CreateSha512(emailAddress.ToLower())` outside the expression, and pass a variable with the result into the expression.

Comment: Regarding 1 and 3, I'd already tried moving `PiSha512.CreateSha512(emailAddress.ToLower())` out of the query and it makes no difference. Regarding 2, it definitely works correctly as it hits the next line and returns the person from the database.

Comment: That is:
`var emailSha = PiSha512.CreateSha512(emailAddress.ToLower());
var personList = collection.Find(p => p.EmailAddressSha512 == emailSha).ToList();`
In debug mode, it gives this:
`MongoDB.Driver.Linq.ExpressionNotSupportedException:
'Expression not supported: (p.EmailAddressSha512 == value(System.Byte[])).` but in the release it's okay, right?

Comment: The exception is thrown in debug mode but it still carries on through the method and works correctly. The exception doesn't alter the program flow

Comment: @WillCalderwood Did you catch the exception or does it get caught somewhere inside the driver or occur in another thread?

Comment: It's caught in the driver.

Comment: @WillCalderwood I think I know what's wrong. You can either enable `Enable Just My Code` or remove all exception catching in `Exception Settings` or rewrite your query `collection.Find(Builders<OurModel>.Filter.Eq(p => p.EmailAddressSha512, emailSha)).ToList()`.

Comment: Using Filter.Eq seems to work around the problem. It's frustrating to not know why, but at least it avoids the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @WillCalderwood The reason for this behavior is that developers are sometimes lazy or pushed by deadlines and kpi and they write "try catch and return" instead of the correct TryGet. Also following DRY and possibly KISS principles